# How to POST multiple pages of same data

Tags: javascript, php, html

first page was registration.php

on pay.php

```
<form action="success.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?> custom="Hidden Element" name="customer">
</form>
```

on success.php
I am not getting any values

```
<?php
$_POST['customer'] = json_decode($_POST['customer'],true);
echo $_POST['customer']['name']; //prints nothing
?>
```

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to reassign to `$_POST`.

Comment: Take a look at the generated HTML. It's likely not valid HTML. You'll need to also use htmlspecialchars to escape any characters in your JSON that mess up your html

Comment: Yes, But I have a large registration form data. so reusing $_POST

Comment: @Progrock empty data

Comment: Syntax error with my former snippet, corrected:  What's the result of dumping the decode? $data = json_decode($_POST['customer'], true); var_dump($data);

Comment: Another approach for longish forms is to flip individual exposed inputs to hidden ones with the collected but escaped values from page to page.  Make sure you (re)validate at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing your data back to the frontend, create a [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) on the server in which your data is temporarily stored across all pages.

When a session is started you can access and set your values by using the `$_SESSION` global variable. This variable is available across all of your files once a session is started and will hold hold your values until the session ends.

```
// Check if there is an active session.
// Otherwise start it.
if ( ! session_id() ) { 
  session_start();
}

// Receive and store.
$customer = $_POST[ 'customer' ]
$_SESSION[ 'customer' ] = $customer;

// Just to show what is in the session.
echo json_decode( $_SESSION[ 'customer' ] );
```

And if you're finished and you want to end the session on the last page then use [`session_destroy()`](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/10/3/5/ending-a-session#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20explicitly,you%20with%20a%20clean%20slate.) to remove the entire session. Another option is to just let the session timeout and remove itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data    = ["name"=>"Thomas O'Leary"];
$encoded = json_encode($data);
//$encoded = bin2hex($encoded);
var_dump($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    //$data = hex2bin($data);
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    var_dump($data);
}
?>
<form method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='data' value='<?= $encoded ?>'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Upon form submission, you'll get this output:

```
array(1) { ["data"]=> string(17) "{"name":"Thomas O" } NULL
```

Indicating data loss, and invalid json.

This is because of the quotes in the hidden field value:

```
<input type='hidden' name='data' value='{"name":"Thomas O'Leary"}'>
```

If you use double quotes for the attribute, you can imagine also running into issues.

So the quotes need some kind of escaping/encoding.

If you uncomment the `bin2hex` and `hex2bin` lines above, you'll get the output:

```
array(1) { ["data"]=> string(50) "7b226e616d65223a2254686f6d6173204f274c65617279227d" } array(1) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Thomas O'Leary" }
```

Some use `htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES);` or `base64_encode($data)` as another workaround.